# Aside,main and footer had issued when using float after nav used pseudo element after with clear both

Tags: css, html

My navigation menu bar looks good (1st time building). After finish building the navigation menu bar and when I started to add my aside, main and footer elements inside the " div " I had some problem.

I tried to float aside and main side by side and footer at the bottom but whenever my mouse hover over to the " nav #Menu .MenuList " that had a sub menu ; the aside, main and footer elements got messed up. All of them seems like got " clear : both " It is fine when my mouse doesn't hover over to the " nav #Menu .MenuList ".

I think is because of the " clear:both " at pseudo elements " nav #Menu::after { ...... } ". I think it " clear : both " for EVERYTHING AFTER the " nav #Menu ".

I didn't want to messed up my navigation, so I tried using " display : inline/inline-table/inline-block " at " nav #Menu .MenuList " instead of using " float : left " and remove the pseudo elements " nav #Menu::after { ...... } " . For this , when my mouse hover over to the " nav #Menu .MenuList " , the background at " nav #Menu { ...... } " then got messed up. The height keeps on changes/The background completely gone.

For your information, I also used CSS reset from HTML5 doctor. (In my honest opinion, I think is good to use the GENERAL CSS reset for BEGINNERS like me to have a better idea in dealing CSS)

HTML5 is here:

```
  <div>

        <header>
        </header>

        <nav>

            <ul id="Menu">
                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                    <ul class="SubMenu">
                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                    <ul class="SubMenu">
                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <aside>
        </aside>

        <main>
        </main>

        <footer>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

CSS is here:

```
div
{
    width : 980px ; height : auto ; margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
}

    header
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; width : 100% ; height : 200px ; margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
    }

    nav
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; font-family : "Comic Sans MS" , cursive , sans-serif ; font-size : 1em ; width : 100% ; height : auto ;
        margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
    }

        nav #Menu
        {
            line-height : 35px ; background : linear-gradient( #00FFFF , #4D70DB ) ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #999999 ;
            border-radius : 5px ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList
        {
            float : left ; width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
        }

        nav #Menu::after
        {
            content : '.' ; visibility : hidden ; clear : both ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList > a
        {
            font-weight : 550 ; text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList:hover
        {
            background : linear-gradient( #A3A3A3 , #5C5C5C ) ;  border-style : solid ; border-color : #999999 ; border-radius : 5px ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList:hover > a
        {
            color : #FFFFFF ;
        }

            nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu
            {
                display : none ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu
            {
                display : block ; position : relative ; top : 100% ; box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ; background-color : #FFFFFF ;
                border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList
            {
                width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList > a
            {
                text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover > a
            {
                color : #7FFFD4 ;
            }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop
                {
                    display : none ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop
                {
                    display : block ; position : absolute ; top : 0 ; left : 100% ; box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ;
                    background-color : #FFFFFF ; border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList
                {
                    width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList > a
                {
                    text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList:hover > a
                {
                    color : #7FFFD4 ;
                }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList .SubDrop
                    {
                        display : none ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop
                    {
                        display : block ; position : absolute ; top : 0 ; left : 101.5% ; box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ;
                        background-color : #FFFFFF ; border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList
                    {
                        width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList > a
                    {
                        text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList:hover > a
                    {
                        color : #7FFFD4 ;
                    }

    aside
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; width : 22.5% ; height : 500px ; float : left ;
    }

    main
    {
        background-color : #000000 ; width : 77.5% ; height : 500px ; float : right ;
    }

    footer
    {
        background-color : red ; width : 100% ; height : 200px ; clear : both ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up a lot of css. But still this is what I did to get it working.

Actually you have floated aside and main, what you should do is float aside to left, and do not float main, just give it a property of overflow hidden.

Plus the dropdown menu was an issue. It should be positioned absolute, so to make it stick above everything. And the border you applied to menu after hover, increased the height of the the menu which was why all the layout messed up

Here,s the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ws6Q/)

**HTML:**

```
  <div>
      <nav>
          <ul id="Menu">
                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                    <ul class="SubMenu">
                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="MenuList">
                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                    <ul class="SubMenu">
                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                    <ul class="SubDrop">
                                        <li class="SubDropList">
                                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="SubMenuList">
                        <a href="#">blabla</a>
                            <ul class="Drop">
                                <li class="DropList">
                                <a href="#">blabla</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <aside>
        </aside>

        <main>
        </main>

        <footer>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
div
{
    width : 980px ; height : auto ; margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
}

    header
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; width : 100% ; height : 200px ; margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
    }

    nav
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; font-family : "Comic Sans MS" , cursive , sans-serif ; font-size : 1em ; width : 100% ; height : auto ;
        margin-left : auto ; margin-right : auto ;
    }

        nav #Menu
        {
            line-height : 35px ; background : linear-gradient( #00FFFF , #4D70DB ) ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #999999 ;
            border-radius : 5px ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList
        {
            float : left ; width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
        }

        nav #Menu::after
        {
            content : '.' ; visibility : hidden ; clear : both ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList > a
        {
            font-weight : 550 ; text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList:hover
        {
            background : linear-gradient( #A3A3A3 , #5C5C5C );
        }

        nav #Menu .MenuList:hover > a
        {
            color : #FFFFFF ;
        }

            nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu
            {
                display : none ;position:absolute;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu
            {
                display : block ;box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ; background-color : #FFFFFF ;
                border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;position:absolute;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList
            {
                width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList > a
            {
                text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
            }

            nav #Menu .MenuList:hover .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover > a
            {
                color : #7FFFD4 ;
            }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop
                {
                    display : none ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop
                {
                    display : block ; position : absolute ; top : 0 ; left : 100% ; box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ;
                    background-color : #FFFFFF ; border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList
                {
                    width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList > a
                {
                    text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
                }

                nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList:hover .Drop .DropList:hover > a
                {
                    color : #7FFFD4 ;
                }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList .SubDrop
                    {
                        display : none ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop
                    {
                        display : block ; position : absolute ; top : 0 ; left : 101.5% ; box-shadow : 0.7px 0.7px 1px #777777 ;
                        background-color : #FFFFFF ; border-width : 1px ; border-radius : 5px ; border-style : solid ; border-color : #d8d9da ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList
                    {
                        width : 7em ; text-align : center ; position : relative ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList > a
                    {
                        text-decoration : none ; color : #000000 ; cursor : default ;
                    }

                    nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu .SubMenuList .Drop .DropList:hover .SubDrop .SubDropList:hover > a
                    {
                        color : #7FFFD4 ;
                    }

    aside
    {
        background-color : #FFFFFF ; width : 22.5% ; height : 500px ; float : left ;
    }

    main
    {
        background-color : #000000 ; width : 77.5% ; height : 500px ;overflow:hidden;
    }

    footer
    {
        background-color : red ; width : 100% ; height : 200px ;
    }
```

Comment: Hi awesometvi , TY for your prompt reply , it's my 1st time self-learning HTML CSS JS PHP and MYSQL so I'm sorry abouting messing up the CSS ( I know some pro coders can make the navigation bar perfectly with very few lines however I just can't follow them properly ) . You are absolutely correct . The real problem is at " nav #Menu .MenuList .SubMenu " which the " position " should be " absolute " and not " relative " , thanks for pointing out my mistake so quickly and accurately . Everything works OK for now :) .

Comment: Yes, it could have been less code than this, but you'll learn this in time. If you need any help, do buzz me.

Comment: Alright , thanks for your kind offer , I will :) . Is my 1st time using this forum though so I'm still not quite familiar , but I mostly visit here to study the problems other posted here .